# map operations(find most occurence element)

Tags: c++

here is code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main(){
map<int ,int>a;
    map<int,int>::iterator it;
    int b[]={2,4,3,5,2,6,6,3,6,4};
     for (int i=0;i<(sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));i++){
         ++a[b[i]];
     }
    // for (it=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++){
        // cout<<(*it).first<<" =>"<<(*it).second<<"\n";
     //}
     int max=a.begin()->second;
     for (it=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++){
         if ((*it).second>max){
             max=(*it).second;
         }
     }
     for (it!=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++){
         if ((*it).second==max){
             cout<<(*it).first<<"\n";
         }
     }




      return 0;
}
```

what i am trying is following  according to  number of occurence of each keys   i  want it print  element which occurs most often in this case 6 but it does not show me result what is mistake?

Comment: One tip is not to reuse variables for different purposes in a function.  That would have found this problem early.  If the type name is sooo big you find it hinders readability, use a `typedef`.  `typedef map<int,int>::iterator MapIt; for (MapIt it = ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your second loop. This:

```
for (it!=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++){
```

Should be this:

```
for (it=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++){
```

By the way, `(*it).first` can be more idiomatically written as `it->first`. The arrow operator (`->`) is a combination of the dereference (`*`) and member access (`.`) operators.

Answer (score 3):

Your second loop should begin with `it=a.begin()`, not `it!=a.begin()`. But why don't you just capture the number that's occurring most frequently when you capture max, and get rid of the second loop altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Given what you're doing, you might consider using a [Boost bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) instead of a plain map. With it, your code would work out something like this:

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/list_of.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {    
    int b[]={2,4,3,5,2,6,6,3,6,4};

    boost::bimap<int, boost::bimaps::list_of<unsigned> > a;

    for (int i=0; i<elements(b); i++)
        ++a.left[b[i]];

    std::cout << a.right.rbegin()->second;
}
```

The one bit of ugliness here is that it depends on what would be the value type to initialize itself properly in the default ctor, which `int` doesn't, so we have to change it from `list_of<unsigned>` to `list_of<uint_proxy>`, with `uint_proxy` defined something like this:

```
class uint_proxy {
    unsigned value;
public:
    uint_proxy() : value(0) {}
    uint_proxy& operator++() { ++value; return *this; }
    unsigned operator++(int) { return value++; }
    operator unsigned() const { return value; }
};
```

In this case, the proxy type adds a bit more length than we'd like, but the main stream of the code is still pretty simple by comparison, and will generally be considerably more efficient -- in particular, it avoids the linear scan to find the key that had the highest count. For the test case that's probably irrelevant, but with a large amount of data is likely to be more significant.